# How to find circular references in a tree

Tags: algorithm, architecture, tree, graph-algorithm

I have a tree structure, pretty much like a DOM.
I need to debug it and clean it from circular references (child is the parent of a parent).
I remember there is an algorithm for this, can't remember the name.
What is the name.

Comment: [Tortoise and Hare algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare)?

Comment: You can use topological sort to find cycles in directed graphs.

Answer (score 4):

Walk the tree using any convenient algorithm; depth-first search is usually a good candidate. Keep track of every node you visit. If you visit a node twice, you have a potential circularity, which you could break that particular circularity by removing the link which lead to the revisited node. But it could be just a join, making the tree a directed acyclic graph (DAG). (See diagram below.)

If you're ok with DAGs but not with circularity, then you need to distinguish the two cases. The easiest way is to maintain two flags for each node instead of one: `visited` and `completed`. On the DFS, you mark the node as visited before visiting the children and completed after visiting the children. (If it's a leaf, just give it both marks.) Now, there are three possibilities when you first visit a node:

1. No marks. No worries.
2. Visited but not completed: circularity
3. Visited and completed: acyclic diamond

The last case looks something like this:

```
           root
            / \
           /   \
          /     \
          a      b
         / \    / \
        /   \  /   \
       /     \/     \
      c     join     d
```